# Django - how to make frontend-customizable sets / groups in models?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create an app, that handles laboratory analyses - something like similar Laboraotory Information System (LIS)

The issue is that i dont know which approach to take.

I am plannin to make it as follows:

"ANALYSES" table - consisting of "name", "ID" of analyses

"PROBES" table - consisiting of "name", "ID", "reference", "VALUE", "measurement".

Also the PROBES will have the field which links it to certain "ANALYSES" instance.

SO it will be like "ANALYSES #1" -> "PROBE1", "PROBE2", "PROBE3"

"ANALYSES #2" -> "PROBE1", "PROBE3"

And so on.

The operator should be capable of adding new analyses and adding probes to this analyses via frontend in one "view" - like "LAB settings" and in another view - to enter values to instances of this analyses (all analyses instances will be linked to some "VISIT" - the service case)

What approach should i take planning the app and models? will it be some Meta classes or just multiple tables linked "manytoone" or "manytomany"?

Will be gratefull for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about this seems particularly complex that a ManyToOne relationship can't handle. Your models would look like this:

```py
class Visit(models.Model):
   ...

class Analysis(models.Model):
   visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit, ...
   ...

class Probe(models.Model):
   analysis = models.ForeignKey(Analysis, ...
   ...
```

If many probes can attach to different analyses or analyses to visits then use a ManyToManyField instead of ForeignKey, note that processing m2m in Django works differently to m21 relations.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: That was helpful, foreighn key is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer!

Currently i am doing something similar to this, if someone interested.
Maybe there are easier ways, but it suits my needs so far.

```
import uuid

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Patient(models.Model):
    class Gender(models.TextChoices):
        male = "Муж"
        female = "Жен"

    surname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=200)
    fathname = models.CharField("Отчество", max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Добавлен", auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.AutoField("Идентификатор", primary_key=True)
    dateofbirth = models.DateField("Дата рождения", null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField("Пол", max_length=3, choices=Gender.choices, default=Gender.male)
    snils = models.DecimalField("СНИЛС", max_digits=11, decimal_places=0, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def returnFIO(self):
        return self.surname + " " + self.name + " " + self.fathname

    def returnAge(self):
        import datetime
        return (datetime.date.today() - self.dateofbirth) / 365 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname + " " + self.name + " " + self.fathname


class Visit(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Пациент")
    id = models.AutoField("Идентификатор", primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Добавлен", auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def returnCreated(self):
        return self.created
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " / " + str(self.created)


from django.db import models
import uuid
from patients.models import Visit


# Create your models here.

class Analiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class AnalizInst(models.Model):
    analiz = models.ForeignKey(Analiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    related_to_visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.analiz) + ' / ' + str(self.id)


class Measurement(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Probe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Название теста", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField("Описание", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField("Идентификатор", default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    related_to_analiz = models.ForeignKey(Analiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Привязка к анализу")
    digits = models.IntegerField("Цифр после запятой", null=True, blank=True)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Измерение")
    probeIsDigital = models.BooleanField("Числовой", default=True)
    referenceText = models.CharField("Референс текст", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    referenceMin = models.DecimalField("Референс MIN", max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
    referenceMax = models.DecimalField("Референс MAX", max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
    defaultInUse = models.BooleanField("Включен по умолчанию", default=True)
    hl7Name = models.CharField("Имя в анализаторе", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    defaultText = models.CharField("Текст значения по умолчанию", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class ProbeInst(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField("Значение", max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
    textvalue = models.CharField("Текстовое значение", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    probe = models.ForeignKey(Probe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Тест")
    id = models.AutoField("Идентификатор", primary_key=True)
    related_to_analyse = models.ForeignKey(AnalizInst, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Привязка к анализу")
    created = models.DateTimeField("Создан", auto_now_add=True)
    inUse = models.BooleanField("В работе", default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.probe)
```

Further i am planning to build some UI and forms input for manual input and make some integrations with HL7 standard to load data directly from lab analyzers.

Django is the best thing that happened to me so far in programming)